# Only variables can be passed by reference error when accessing array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, variables

I'm getting the fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference when trying to access a xml string within a array. I log the request xml and response xml into an array but when trying to access these again keep getting this error, the code looks like this.

```
 Array
 (
     [return] => Array
     (
        [request] => "<xml></xml>"
        [response] = ?"<xml></xml>"
     )
 )
```

I don't understand why the code is inserting the ? before the xml string.

The way I form the array is:

```
 $ar = array('request' => $request , 'response' => $response);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code where you were creating that array

Comment: I can't assume which code is creating array and inserting `?`.

Comment: the top code is the structure of the array when print_r and the bottom is creating the array